# How can I bulk insert a CSV file in SQL Server that includes a column with JSON arrays?

Tags: bulkinsert

SQL Server bulk insert - need help, having problem to load file with layout last column json and have [ ]:

SKU,Name,Prices
"1268","Hat",[{"price_id":"11866","website_id":"1"},{"price_id":"11867","website_id":"3"}]
"1275","Cat",[{"price_id":"11896","website_id":"2"},{"price_id":"11897","website_id":"4"}]